# selecting all the records from the database using jquery ajax in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

i want to generate the table of contents from database.. using jquery ajax in asp.net, i am using sql server 2008 as a backend. for this i created a webmethod in my normal aspx page. and on the clientside wrote the ajax script to fetch records but when i loop through the results, i gets message undefined and nothing happens.. i want to generate table out of the records from database below is my webmethod.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static Poll[] GetPollDetailed()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_SelectQuestion", con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteid", 3);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        List<Poll> _poll1 = new List<Poll>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Poll _poll = new Poll();
            _poll.QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(row["questionID"]);
            _poll.Question = row["question"].ToString();
            _poll.Published = Convert.ToInt32(row["visible"]);
            _poll.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Added_Date"]);
        }
        return _poll1.ToArray();
    }
public class Poll
{
    public Poll() { }
    private int _questionId, _published;
    private string _question;
    private DateTime _date;

    public int QuestionID
    {
        get { return _questionId; }
        set { _questionId = value; }
    }

    public string Question
    {
        get { return _question; }
        set { _question = value; }
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = value; }
    }

    public int Published
    {
        get { return _published; }
        set { _published = value; }
    }
}
</code>
and below is my script.  
<code>
$(this).load(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AddPollAJax.aspx/GetPollDetailed",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    alert(data[i].QuestionID);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error: " + data.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</code>
```

can any one please help me to resolve this issue, i am very curious about it.

Comment: Have you tested using FireFox FireBug extension? What response did you get from the HTTP POST?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `type: "GET"` in the jQuery ajax call? And are you sure that `_poll1.ToArray();` generates valid JSON?

Comment: @ain: I dont have any idea.. can you tell me how shall i check.. coz when i tried alerting data.. as it is array it should return object. but does not display anything, but atleast it does not go in error. it goes in success and shows nothing

Comment: @Abbas Why don't you use `$.getJSON('AddPollAJax.aspx/GetPollDetailed', function(data) {your_success_code_here});`? Oh, and about your asp.net code - I have no idea what it does, I don't do asp.net, but I suspect the `.toArray()` isn't returning JSON.

Comment: @ain: thanks for the reply. i tried the above code inside the document.load function.. but still no change.. i dont even get normal alert with string... i guess nothing is happening with getJSON

Comment: Add this before get call: `$('body').ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception){alert(exception)});`

Comment: Invalid JSON: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
</title></head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="AddPollAJax.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="hP8DrZMpHGeABurXdr2IcRY8jMzK+5Ayj3BI0bptYaeZn7amHg1E4nNUCVS1+ScBxUQNKDzsGgfP3Fnv7yq7JtdZV3o=" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" value="" />
</div>
<div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @ain let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2300/discussion-between-abbas-and-ain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your service is configured correctly to return JSON data, issue lies at your js code fragment for success callback i.e.

```
success: function (data) {
     for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        alert(data[i].QuestionID);
     }
},
```

MS ASP.NET script services always return a wrapped JSON due to security issues, so you need unwrap resultant JS object to get the actual data. So you need to change the code to

```
success: function (result) {
     var data = result.d;  // actual response will be in this property
     for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        alert(data[i].QuestionID);
     }
},
```

BTW, ASP.NET Web Services are now considered legacy, so I will suggest you to migrate to WCF services instead.

Comment: thanks vinay thanks for your help... thats the issue i was facing from last 2 days, but hats off to you, you just resolved it... if you dont mind, can you give me the same example for WCF...

Comment: @Abbas, using WCF services is not very much different than asmx service. At server side, you will have wcf (svc) service with a bit of configuration. You will find plenty of samples on web. Here's one such sample: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111710-1.aspx